# Flexbox's row-reverse property is not reversing the line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a Navbar for my website and I noticed that if I had the links on the right using `float: right` they would reverse the order. I thought that I could reverse them back by using Flexbox's
`flex-direction: reverse-row`. This does not appear to work though?

Here's the code that *should* be responsible for re-reversing this effect:

```css
.headerItem {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Any hints/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer. @jmag has provided some useful info, and some further Googling helped as well. The new navbar looks like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <span id="headerLogo">XaafCode</span>

    <div id="navbar">
      <a href="/index.html" class="headerItem" id="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="headerItem">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="/contact.html" class="headerItem">Contact me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS I have this now, which easily fixed it:

```
#navbar, #header { justify-content: space-between; }
```

Answer (score 0):

float property is not part of flex. This will prevent it from doing what it is suppose to, because you are forcing it to float to right. Flex has its own way of doing that. its called justify-content -  flex-start, flex-end, center, space-between and space-around. Try which one works for you.